# How to get the list of repeated entries in a table with its count

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get the list of categories with number of vehicles from the below table (in descending order of no. of vehicles).

Vehicle | category

```
ab        A       
cd        A        
ef        A       
gh        B
ij        B
kl        C
```

Expected output:

```
A  3
B  2
C  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function `count()` with a GROUP BY:

```
select category, count(*) Total
from yourtable
group by category
order by total desc;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50240/2)

Comment: Is it display the categories in descending order of count?

Comment: @jomin You just will add an `order by total desc`, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Simply `GROUP BY`, and retrieve the count.  That is,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS repetitions FROM Vehicles GROUP BY category
```